# HTML5 semantic markup for main contents heading

Tags: wordpress, html

I come to you for help once again, Stack Overflow. This time I have trouble understanding the semantics of HTML5 regarding a heading for the main contents of my site. Below are two examples, which one should I use? Perhaps I should go a completely different way?

**Edit**: I mixed up the code examples!

### Example 1

Using this code I get an outline like:

1. Category: foo
2. Blog post #1
3. Blog post #2

Which seems incorrect, since the blog posts are posted under the category?

```
<header id="header">
    <h1>My awesome website!</h1>
    <!-- Primary navigation and such -->
</header>
<div id="content">
    <section id="title">
        <h1>Category: foo</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </section>
    <article>
        <h1>Blog post #1</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Blog post #2</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

### Example 2

Using this code I get an outline like:

1. Category: foo

   1. Blog post #1
   2. Blog Post #2

Which seems correct to me, but [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/) says that `<section>` should not be used as a main/primary content wrapper.

Also if I were to use this example, would I exchange `<section id="content>` with a `<div id="content">` if there is no natural heading for the main content (like the index page where all posts are shown)?

```
<header id="header">
    <h1>My awesome website!</h1>
    <!-- Primary navigation and such -->
</header>
<section id="content">
    <header id="title">
        <h1>Category: foo</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </header>
    <article>
        <h1>Blog post #1</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Blog post #2</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using h1-h6 tags the old fashioned way.

```
<h1>My awesome website!</h1>

<section> 

    <h2>Category: foo</h2>
    <p>Some content</p>

    <article>
        <h3>Blog post #1</h3>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </article>

   <article>
       <h3>Blog post #2</h3>
       <p>Some content</p>
   </article>
</section>

<section>  
    <h2>Category: bar</h2>
    <p>some content</p>

    <article>
        <h3>Blog post #3</h3>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </article>

    <article>
       <h3>Blog post #4</h3>
       <p>Some content</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

This is similar to [HTML5Doctor's own example](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) of a `<section>` containing `<article>`s.

Technically, you could replace the `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags with `<h1>`, and that would be just as valid. Using h1-h6 has the advantage of maintaining backwards compatibility with older user agents (screen readers in particular).

Comment: Do you have a source for your the assertion about when `<h1>` should replace `<h3>`? The spec is [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/headings-and-sections.html#headings-and-sections) and I can't find anything that supports that.

Comment: That's an example of why you would use h1. I didn't mean to imply it's the only valid reason.  It really doesn't matter as far as HTML5 is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: http://visitmix.com/writings/article-vs-section-weve-finally-gone-mad

Looks like you want

```
<section id="content">
    <h1>Category: foo</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
  <article>
    <h1>Blog post #1</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Blog post #2</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Yep, I like this one, and I have nothing against using the section tag in this case... the only thing I don't quite understand is why you're all afraid of using h2 (or even h3) tags inside the articles? That's the only thing I would change.

Answer (score 0):

I would markup the page similar to what @Patrick McElhaney has done – you have have one `SECTION` for each category. I've just added another wrapper named 'content', to allow grouping of sub-content-elements. This reflects your original layout.

```
<header id="header">
    <h1>My awesome website!</h1>
    <!-- Primary navigation and such -->
</header>

<section id="content">
    <section class="category" id="catFoo">
        <hgroup id="title">
            <h2>Category: Foo</h2>
            <p>Category Description</p>
        </hgroup>
        <article>
            <h3>Blog post #Foo1</h3>
            <p>Some content</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h3>Blog post #Foo2</h3>
            <p>Some content</p>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section class="category" id="catBar">
        <hgroup id="title">
            <h2>Category: Bar</h2>
            <p>Category Description</p>
        </hgroup>
        <article>
            <h3>Blog post #Bar1</h3>
            <p>Some content</p>
        </article>
    </section>
</section>
```